# Combine prebuilt-invoice model with custom model?

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I'm attempting to extract data from invoices in Danish.
The prebuilt-invoice model works really great except it can't extract danish payment details.

I can create a custom model and learn it to extract these payment relevant fields, but can I combine it with the prebuilt-invoice model, so I don't have to train it for the fields that this model already covers?

Or do I need to first make an request to use the prebuilt-invoice model, and then another requesting using my custom model? For cost reasons, I would like to avoid this...

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to combine prebuilt models with custom models in Azure AI Document Intelligence. If you have any documents that are not being analyzed correctly, you would need to create a custom model to extract the relevant fields.

Comment: Thank you Ram. When I need most fields extracted by the prebuilt-invoice model, and some additional fields. Would it then be the smartes to first analyse the document using the prebuilt model, and then my custom model or are there smarter ways? It does incur significance cost (analysing all documents twice), so I'm trying to figure out if we're approaching this the correct way.